# Evaluate integral, the probability of one being the of max of a set of iid half-logistic distributed random variables

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

Suppose random variables $$X_i \sim iid \text{ half-logistic} (\mu_i, 1),$$
where $\mu_i \in \mathbb{R}$ is the location parameter and $1$ is the scaling parameter, $\forall i\in I$; and $I$ is a finite-set with cardinality $|I|>2$.

What is the probability that $X_j$ achieves the maximum of $X_i, \forall i\in I$?
i.e., what is
$$\text{Prob} (X_j > \max_{i\neq j} X_i) = \text{Prob} (X_j \geq \max_{i\in I} X_i)=\text{Prob} (X_j \geq X_i, \forall i\in I)?$$
Is there a closed form or a good approximation?

---

Some information about half-logistic distribution can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-logistic_distribution) (only the standard half-logistic, i.e., $(0,1)$, is shown).
Basically, it is the distribution of the absolute value of a random variable with logistic distribution.

The $\text{half-logistic} (\mu_i, 1)$ has cdf:
$$\dfrac{1-\exp\big[-(x-\mu_i)\big]}{1+\exp\big[-(x-\mu_i)\big]},$$
and pdf:
$$\dfrac{2\exp\big[-(x-\mu_i)\big]}{\Big(1+\exp\big[-(x-\mu_i)\big]\Big)^2}.$$
Hence, I think
\begin{align*}
\text{Prob} (X_j \geq X_i, \forall i\in I) &= \prod_{i\in I} \text{Prob} (X_i\leq X_j )\\
&= \prod_{i\in I} \text{Prob} (X_i - \mu_j \leq X_j - \mu_j)
\end{align*}
where
$$X_i - \mu_j \sim \text{half-logistic} (\mu_i-\mu_j, 1) \,\,\,\,\text{ and } \,\,\,\, X_j - \mu_j \sim \text{half-logistic} (0, 1).$$
Hence, the probability
\begin{align*}
=\int_\mathbb{R} \dfrac{2\exp(-x)}{\Big(1+\exp(-x)\Big)^2} \prod_{i\in I} \dfrac{1-\exp\big[-(x-(\mu_i-\mu_j))\big]}{1+\exp\big[-(x-(\mu_i-\mu_j))\big]} dx.
\end{align*}
Numerical simulation should be able to approximate this, but that's not what I'm looking for.
And I cannot solve this integral. Any idea helps! Thanks!